# How to compare user input (from std::cin) to a string?

Tags: c++, string, comparison

So this one sounds very easy but I am getting some strange behavior.

In my program there is the following code:

```
std::cout << "Would you like to generate a complexity graph or calculate global complexity? (graph/global)\n";
char ans[6];
std::cin >> ans;

if (ans != "global") std::cout << ">>" << ans << "<<" << std::endl;
```

When I run my program and type in "global" when I'm prompted for input, the program returns:

```
>>global<<
```

Why does the if statement evaluate as `true`?

Comment: ^^^ Or use an `std::string` instead of a `char` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) or [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp) for comparison of c-style strings. `ans != "global"` is just comparing the memory address pointed by the pointer, not the content of string.
2. `char ans[6];` should be `char ans[7];`, for `"global"`, you need one more `char` for the terminating null character `'\0'`.

You should use `std::string` instead, to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `ans` as array of char, thus if `if (ans != "global")` expression, `ans` means pointer to the beginning of the string. So you compare two pointers which are obviously not equal and your expression evaluates to true. If you still want to declare `ans` as a C-style string, you may construct an `std::string` from it before comparing:

```
if (std::string(ans) != "global") {......}
```

Or just declare `ans` as `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: with c++14 literals, `ans != "global"s` is available